# Equivalent of Z-Index in Apple News

Tags: ios9, apple-news

I'm looking for something that will enable me to keep one item in front of others in my Apple News documents--the equivalent of a z-index in CSS.  I haven't found anything in the documentation that seems to apply.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to z-index.

You can however have components overlay images and videos by having sub-components on a container that is styled with a fill.